# Android - Button with multiple drawables

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have to create a button as the following image:

[image: Sample button]

It almost ok, like this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_shape_button"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textColor="@color/colorSecundary"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ico_alerta"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ico_seta_r"
    android:text="@string/main_botao_painel_alertas" />
```

Where "@drawable/main_shape_button" is the following:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="-1dp" android:right="-1dp" android:bottom="-1dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But, I still have to add the yellow indicator with the number of unviewed alerts of the user.

How can I achieve it?

## Update:

I achieve it extending the button class:

```
public class AlertButton extends Button {

    public AlertButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AlertButton(Context context,  AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AlertButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int h = canvas.getHeight();
        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        //Calculate the x coordinate 
        float xCoodinate = (3*w)/4;
        //Calculate 80% of the button height to the ratio.
        float ratio = (h/2) * 0.8f;

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTertiary));

        canvas.drawCircle(x, h/2 , ratio, paint);

        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPaint.setTextSize(50f);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        String text = "10";

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

        float yCoordinate = 71f; //hard coded
        canvas.drawText(text, x, yCoordinate, textPaint);
    }
}
```

However I didn't discover how calculate the y-coordinate for the text being drawn.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `Button` i would create a layout with the desired look and make it clickable by the `android:clickable="true"` attribute.

Another option is to create your own custom `Component` by extending `Button` and override it's appropriate methods.

Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) out for more information on Custom Components.

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute in to android:clickable="true"

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/your_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_shape_button"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:textColor="@color/colorSecundary"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ico_alerta"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ico_seta_r"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/main_botao_painel_alertas" />
```